# WP7 game: Call Web Service when Deactivated (tombstoning)

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7, xna, tombstoning

I'm running into a weird problem and I want to know if it is normal or if I'm missing something.

Here's the situation :

1. I'm developping a multiplayer game in XNA for WP7
2. When a user quits the game (enters in tombstoning or exiting), I want to warn others players that a player left
3. I override the `Game.OnExiting()` method to call my Web Service, and I have put a breakpoint on this line
4. Each time, the breakpoint gets hit, the call is made, no error occurs, but the server never receives the call

Is it normal that the call is not processed on the server because the game is exiting?

Here's the code :

```
    protected override void OnExiting(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance.IsOnlineGame && !Guide.IsVisible)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.Multiplayer.QuitGame();
        }

        base.OnExiting(sender, args);
    }

    internal void QuitGame()
    {
        _client.QuitGameAsync(GameManager.Instance.GameId, _myRank);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the client to tell you the user quit?  Can't you just tell the other players once the server notices the connection has been terminated?

Comment: Because it would be faster to push this information to other players and because the server doesn't maintain a list of active connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scientific explanations:

> HttpWebRequests are dispatched from the UI thread so if your app/game UI thread never updates after your call to quit the game the request will never be sent. You can test this by creating a web request and then looping until the request is completed (waiting on the async result complete state) - the request will never be sent and you will wait forever. You could try introducing a delay of a few hundred milliseconds (without putting the UI thread to sleep which would still block the request) and see if the request is made. In XNA this would mean doing nothing for a few update calls to see if the request is sent. You could also use a timer.

Credits : dadoo Games on http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/79737.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your app only has a very short time to perform any operations when exiting. Calling a web service has the potential to take longer than may be permitted to you.

It's not clear from the amount of code you have posted what resources are available to make the call (and pass necessary data) either.

If you do do this you shouldn't rely on that message being sent to the server. This may have implications for your applicaiton logic.

Comment: +1 and it's even worse than Matt says - since you are calling `QuitGameAsync` then you need another thread to run before you can even start sending the message to the server. Your chances of this thread getting scheduled are at best 50/50 - and quite likely are close to 0. If you really need to send this message then you'll need to put some code in to make sure the call occurs - but this might suck from a user perspective.

Comment: Well, I think you have it right. I'll need to use a timer to inform players. Thanks! I post the answer receive on MSDN forum.